# Select Join Tables with parameters using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can somebody tell me pls where the error is in my code below? I have been trying to join two tables to get exam scores but I always get the error that `Warning: PDOStatement:execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:direcory'

Here is my code:

```
function getEmptyExamScores($conn, $course_code, $level, $year, $semester) { 
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM exams INNER JOIN register_course ON exams.course_code = register_course.course_code WHERE exams.course_code = :exams.course_code AND level = :level AND year = :year AND semester = :semester;');
$stmt->execute(['exams.course_code' => $course_code, 'level' => $level, 'year' => $year, 'semester' => $semester]);
return $stmt->fetchAll(); 
}
```

Comment: I'd start by using `:course_code` instead of `:exams.course_code`

Comment: `'exam_year' => $exam_year` - There's no such placeholder in your query. And also no such PHP variable defined.

Comment: Well, I did that already. Worthy of mention the course_code is a field name in both exams and register_course table. That might creat a problem.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel that's 'year' there. It is there.

Comment: I should also mention that I tested the code and it worked before I joined the tables.

Comment: `year` is there. But `exam_year` isn't.

Comment: Are `level`, `year` and `semester` columns from which table?

Comment: @fedeisas they're from exams table

Comment: @Babangida can you take a look at my response?

Comment: @fedeisas I have seen it and didn't find where to reply you. It was exactly what I needed. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Babangida can you tell me why it didn't worked?

Comment: @fedeisas I get the same error I received earlier.

Comment: @Babangida the problem is coming from another query.

Comment: @fedeisas It worked thanks. I realized that I have made some mistakes at the placeholder part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First advice: readability matters :-)

I'd suggest using SQL alias for your tables, because it makes queries easier to read.

Also you can specify which columns belong to which table. Otherwise, let's say a year from now you have a `year` column on both tables, and your query is going to fail because the parser won't know which column you are referring to.

I'm assuming `level`, `year` and `semester` are part of the `exams` table.

```
<?php

function getEmptyExamScores($conn, $course_code, $level, $year, $semester) {
    $query = 'SELECT *
        FROM exams e
        INNER JOIN register_course rc ON e.course_code = rc.course_code
        WHERE e.course_code = :course_code
            AND e.level = :level
            AND e.year = :year
            AND e.semester = :semester';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute([
        'course_code' => $course_code,
        'level' => $level,
        'year' => $year,
        'semester' => $semester,
    ]);

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```